# Buddypress overriding author url

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am getting author's url on Wordpress from outside the loop using this:

```
<?php
get_author_posts_url( $author_id, $author_nicename );
?>
```

Which works fine by delivering the author URL in this format -

**mysitename.com/author/john-james**.

However when Buddypress is enabled, this same URL changes to

**mysitename.com/members/john-james**

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

`get_author_posts_url()` calls `$wp_rewrite->get_author_permastruct()` which by default returns:

```
$this->author_structure = $this->front . $this->author_base . '/%author%';
```

The `WP_Rewrite` class has this filter which may let you change the values:

```
apply_filters( 'author_rewrite_rules', array $author_rewrite )
```

[All this is info is from the WP Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually have to use this code - `<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/author/<?php echo($user_name); ?>` where `$user_name = $user_info->user_nicename;`

This also gets me - **mysitename.com/author/john-james**

There may be other ways, but this allows me to use the two URLs together for different purposes, one  to check the author's profile (through buddypress) and the other to view all author's articles.